# Oracle: Comparing multiple entries within a table

Tags: sql, oracle

Say if I had a table that kept track of members and invoices. Each member can have multiple invoices.

My question is, how would I list members that have two invoices dated within the same week of the year and have them appear only once?

Second, How would I list members that have more than 1 invoice?

Comment: What does "invoices dated within the same week of the year" mean to you?  That any two invoices are less than 7 days apart?  That two invoices appear in the same Sunday to Saturday period?  The same Monday to Sunday period?  The same ISO week http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date  Something else?

Comment: GROUP BY or DISTINCT allows you to have records that only appear once.  Functions like COUNT allow you to produce aggregate results.  HAVING (used with GROUP BY) allows you to filter on the aggregate results.

Comment: GROUP BY week, HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2

Comment: `inner join` on `memberid`, `group by memberid`, `having count(*) = 2` or `>1`

Comment: Within the same week, means your standard week, monday through sunday. I would have specified otherwise. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Read up on GROUP BY, JOIN, HAVING and COUNT.

Comment: Watch out for new years, with week parts in both years...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple case of group by and having...

Data setup:

```
create table member (id NUMBER, name VARCHAR2(10));
create table invoice (id NUMBER, member_id NUMBER, invoice_date DATE);

insert into member values (1, 'Joe');
insert into member values (2, 'Sally');
insert into member values (3, 'Bill');

insert into invoice values (1, 1, sysdate);
insert into invoice values (2, 1, sysdate - 1);
insert into invoice values (3, 1, sysdate - 7);
insert into invoice values (4, 2, sysdate - 5);
insert into invoice values (5, 2, sysdate - 3);
insert into invoice values (6, 3, sysdate - 6);
```

Question #1:  Two invoices same week.

```
select member_id, count(id) invoice_count, to_char(sysdate, 'IW') week_of_year 
  from invoice
  group by member_id, to_char(sysdate, 'IW')
  having count(id) >= 2;
```

Question #2:  More than once invoice.

```
   select member_id, b.name member_name, count(a.id) invoice_count
      from invoice a, member b
      where a.member_id = b.id
      group by member_id, b.name
      having count(a.id) > 1;
```

The format model "IW" in oracle is the number of the week of the year for the given date, per the documentation:  "Week of year (1-52 or 1-53) based on the ISO standard."

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

Comment: to_char(invoice_date, 'IW')?